# Firebase auth verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a sign up form where a user is required to type their email and password. Firebase won't let you create a user if their email and password don't meet certain conditions, namely, it should be a valid email and a password should be strong enough. On top of that validation I have that of my own. What I would like to do actually is somehow inform the user about those validation errors thrown by Firebase.

Problem: I can show the firebase errors only after the submit button is clicked.

It would be nice if it were possible to do this before a form submit. That's to say, if a number of symbols typed by a user in the password field is less than 6 the user should be notified about that.

So I think it would make sense to listen to what a user types and when they stop, make a request to some endpoint that returns an error object if the values entered don't meet the criteria. The responsibility of this request is to validate the fields and that's it.

Is it possible to make such a request in Firebase? From what I know it's impossible but I'd like to make sure, perhaps there're some nice workarounds or something.

Comment: This is something you're going to have to code up on your own.  The Firebase SDK isn't going to make this any easier for you.  I suggest being prepared to handle rejected promises from the call to [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createuserwithemailandpassword) in order to determine if there's a problem with what the user entered, and prompt the user accordingly.

Comment: That sounds like an answer Doug.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well I see, so basically it turns out that I'll have to implement all this verification stuff on my own and handle responses from the firebase auth verification feature as a fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you're going to have to code up on your own. The Firebase SDK isn't going to make this any easier for you. I suggest being prepared to handle rejected promises from the call to [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createuserwithemailandpassword) in order to determine if there's a problem with what the user entered, and prompt the user accordingly.

Comment: It's really strange that they don't provide the possibility to make such a request...seems like a good reason for a feature request.

Comment: Sure, you are always free to send a feature request to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support